Dynamic Configuration Updates and SSR in Next.js with next-export-i18n
I’m currently developing a website using Next.js, and I need to dynamically update configuration values using a configuration file without rebuilding the application. To achieve this, I’ve implemented getInitialProps in my _app.js. Here’s an example of the code I’m using:
import NextApp from 'next/app';
import MainLayout from '@/components/MainLayout';

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MainLayout>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await NextApp.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps };
};

export default App;

While this approach works for dynamic configurations, it introduces a problem: using getInitialProps disables Automatic Static Optimization in Next.js. This is important because certain features, like static generation and SSR, rely on optimization to function effectively.
I’ve run into an issue when trying to use the next-export-i18n package for translations on my Server-Side Rendered (SSR) pages. Here’s the code that triggers the issue:
import { useTranslation, useLanguageQuery } from 'next-export-i18n';
const { t } = useTranslation();
const [query] = useLanguageQuery();

On SSR pages, this results in client-side exceptions when the hooks are executed.
Is there a solution that allows me to:

Dynamically update configuration values without needing to rebuild the application
Continue using next-export-i18n for translations on SSR pages
Avoid client-side exceptions while preserving Automatic Static Optimization (or a similar level of performance)

I’m looking for suggestions or best practices that can help maintain SSR and translation functionality while allowing for dynamic configuration updates.
I tried the following approach:
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DynamicUseTranslation = dynamic(() => import('next-export-i18n').then(mod => mod.useTranslation), { ssr: false });
const DynamicUseLanguageQuery = dynamic(() => import('next-export-i18n').then(mod => mod.useLanguageQuery), { ssr: false });

However, it's still not working as expected.
